# Jumping exactly at some predetermined page

Tags: feature-request, navigation

When trying to reach some page in "newest" or "unanswered" questions (or wherever), is it possible to choose *somehow* the precise page where we want to go instead of scrolling down and jumping two-by-two pages each time?

For example, if I want to go to page 65, I have to do the scrolling and jumping tens of times! Even choosing "50 questions per page" this is way too slow...

Thanks.

Comment: I've created [meta-tag:navigation] tag for this question. Meta.SO has [such tag](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/navigation), so I thought that it might be useful here, too. We will see whether other question related to this topic come.

Answer (score 8):

Edit the url? For example, clicking on page 5 of the display for questions on meta gives this url

```
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest
```

we can edit it to

```
http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions?page=65&sort=newest
```

and voila! Page 65 reached.

Comment: +1 Superb, @Willie! Thanks a lot, although I think there should be someway to choose this from within SE mathematics without going to URL.

Comment: @Don: I changed your question to be tagged "feature request" on account of your comment.

Comment: This is an instance of a generally-useful skill that @DonAntonio might do well to practice.